# How can I use Pandas or Openpyxl to classify a database in Excel based on supplier names?

Tags: python, data-science

I want to classify a database in excel using Python (Pandas or Openpyxl), where I have the name of the supplier in the 1st column and I want to fill in the type in the 2nd column. But I need to identify the supplier as a string (because the cells of the suppliers may vary). How can I do it?

I thought that this could work, but it's adding "SHOPEE" (example) for all the lines:

```
x = [table.loc[:,"supplier"].str.contains("SHOPEE")]
for x in table:
    table["TYPE"] = "SHOPEE"
display(table)
```

Comment: Right, because `table["TYPE"]` refers to every row in the table.  Note that you never used your `for` loop variable.  I suspect it would work if you changed it to `x["TYPE"] = "SHOPEE"`, but a better answer is below in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this as a template, make changes wherever you need

```
import pandas as pd

# Load the Excel file into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx')

# Define a dictionary to map suppliers to their corresponding types
supplier_types = {
    'SHOPEE': 'Type 1',
    'SUPPLIER2': 'Type 2',
    'SUPPLIER3': 'Type 3',
    # Add more mappings as needed
}

# Iterate over the rows of the DataFrame
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    supplier = str(row['supplier'])  # Convert supplier to a string
    for key, value in supplier_types.items():
        if key in supplier:
            df.at[index, 'TYPE'] = value  # Assign the corresponding type

# Display the updated DataFrame
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner expression below returns a list of booleans, True if the column contains a string, False if not.  Pandas's fancy indexing then does the assignment only on those rows where the boolean is True.

```
table.loc[table["supplier"].str.contains("SHOPEE"),"TYPE"] = "SHOPEE"
```

So, for example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
  [ "what", ""],
  [ "SHOPEE", ""],
  [ "what", ""],
  [ "SHOPEE", ""],
  [ "what", ""],
  [ "SHOPEE", ""]
]
df = pd.DataFrame( data, columns=['supplier','TYPE'])
df.loc[df['supplier'].str.contains('SHOPEE'),'TYPE'] = 'SHOPEE'
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  supplier    TYPE
0     what        
1   SHOPEE  SHOPEE
2     what        
3   SHOPEE  SHOPEE
4     what        
5   SHOPEE  SHOPEE
```